# Math equation with cases and division signs

Tags: equations, amsmath, cases

```
\begin{equation*}
    \theta({P,\bar{Cl}}) = 
    \begin{cases}
        S(P,\widehat{Cl}) + (S(P,\widehat{Cl}) \times  ((\bar{R}-\widehat{R})/\bar{R})) & \widehat{Cl} \textless \bar{Cl} \\
        S(P,\widehat{Cl}) - (S(P,\widehat{Cl}) \times  ((\widehat{R}-\bar{R})/\bar{R})) & \widehat{Cl} \textgreater \bar{Cl} 
    \end{cases}
    \label(eq: state}
\end{equation*}
```

How can I make it look more beautiful and legible?
I would like to push the division sign below so that it is more legible

any ideas are welcome

Comment: Use \frac{}{} instead of a division line.  But this depends one what is more beautiful to you.

Comment: I tried `\frac` what is the difference between `frac` and `frax` or is it a typo?

Comment: I did that then. any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What does beautiful mean to you? This question is very subjective which makes it hard to answer. Why don't you like \frac? If you use dcases, you will have display style if that is beautiful. I think you need to load mathtools instead of amsmath instead though for dcases.

Comment: I will take a look at some examples on the wiki page in that case.

Comment: Is it just me or those lines are equal?

Comment: @percusse - I'd noticed too that they're de facto equal, but chose not to draw extra attention to the fact in my answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I would use `displaystyle` fractions. Next I would replace the non-extensible `\bar` with `\widebar`, borrowed from the `mathx`(it's in the `mathabx` bundle, without loading the `mathabx` package since it changes many symbols.As I'm changing symbols, I also replaced `\widehat` with mathx's version, with I named `varwidehat` to not interfere  with defaults. Finally I changed `Cl` into a math operator (`Cl`), as I suspect it is so. For the moment it looks like the product of the two variables C and l. If I'm wrong, all you have to do is replacing back `\Cl` with `Cl`.

To prevent having too large vertical spacing with respect to the surrounding text, due to the fractions, I kill the first line fraction height with a `\smash[t]{…}` command, and the second line fraction depth with `\smash[b]{…}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\Cl{Cl}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\varwidehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\theta({P,\widebar{\Cl}}) =
\begin{cases}
    S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) + S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) \times \smash[t]{ \dfrac{\widebar{R}-\varwidehat{R}}{\widebar{R}}} &\qquad \varwidehat{\Cl} < \widebar{\Cl} \\[1.5ex]
    S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) - S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) \times \smash[b]{\dfrac{\varwidehat{R}-\widebar{R}}{\widebar{R}}} &\qquad \varwidehat{\Cl} > \widebar{\Cl}
\end{cases}
\label{(eq: state}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious use of `\smash[t]{...}` in the first line and `\smash[b]{...}` in the second. You may want to explain in more detail what these macros do, just in case the OP isn't an experienced user of the `amsmath` package...

Comment: You're right, I'll do it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't compilable since it contains macros such as `\textgreater` and `\textless` that shouldn't occur in math mode. The argument of a `\label` command has to be enclosed in curly braces, by the way.

You didn't give any hints as to *your* criteria for beauty and legibility, so I'll have to use my own. :-) There's nothing terribly wrong with the look once the code's been fixed so that it compiles. (I'm talking purely about the aestetics, of course; I can't tell if the math is correct or not...) I did notice that the overall look is quite cramped. You could use a `dcases*` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package) instead of the basic `cases` environment to provide a bit more whitespace. Next, there's a minor issue with the uneven usage of accents: the "hats" are uniformly "wide", but the "bars" are not. I suggest using `\overline` for the `Cl` terms. Third, I'd get rid of two redundant pairs of parentheses on each line. Finally, since there's no point in providing a `\label` to an unnumbered equation, I'd either comment it out or get rid of it entirely.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases*' environment
\begin{document}
Before:
\begin{equation*}
    \theta({P,\bar{Cl}}) = 
    \begin{cases}
        S(P,\widehat{Cl}) + (S(P,\widehat{Cl}) \times  ((\bar{R}-\widehat{R})/\bar{R})) & \widehat{Cl} < \bar{Cl} \\
        S(P,\widehat{Cl}) - (S(P,\widehat{Cl}) \times  ((\widehat{R}-\bar{R})/\bar{R})) & \widehat{Cl} > \bar{Cl} 
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq: state}
\end{equation*}

After:
\begin{equation*}
\theta(P,\overline{Cl}\,) = 
\begin{dcases*}
        S(P,\widehat{Cl}) + S(P,\widehat{Cl}) \times  (\bar{R}-\widehat{R})/\bar{R} 
& if $\widehat{Cl} < \overline{Cl}$ \\
        S(P,\widehat{Cl}) - S(P,\widehat{Cl}) \times  (\widehat{R}-\bar{R})/\bar{R} 
& if $\widehat{Cl} > \overline{Cl} $
    \end{dcases*}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions that might make the equation easier to read.

[image]

Code based on @Bernard s answer.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\Cl{Cl}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\varwidehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\theta({P,\widebar{\Cl}}) =
\begin{cases}
    S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) \times \left( 1 +
    \dfrac{\widebar{R}-\varwidehat{R}}{\widebar{R}}\right) &\qquad
    \varwidehat{\Cl} < \widebar{\Cl} \\[3.0ex]
    S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) \times \left( 1 -
    \dfrac{\widebar{R}-\varwidehat{R}}{\widebar{R}}\right) &\qquad
    \varwidehat{\Cl} > \widebar{\Cl}
\end{cases}
\label{(eq: state}
\end{equation*}

or perhaps, if this difference has some separate semantic value

Let
%
\begin{equation*}
\Delta =     \dfrac{\widebar{R}-\varwidehat{R}}{\widebar{R}}.
\end{equation*}

Then
\begin{equation*}
\theta({P,\widebar{\Cl}}) =
\begin{cases}
    S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) \times ( 1 + \Delta)
    &\qquad
    \varwidehat{\Cl} < \widebar{\Cl} \\[1.5ex]
    S(P,\varwidehat{\Cl}) \times ( 1 - \Delta)
    &\qquad
    \varwidehat{\Cl} > \widebar{\Cl}
\end{cases}
\label{(eq: state}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `cases` environment would look more appealing if the large parentheses had the same size on both lines. Currently, the parentheses seem to be too small on the first line and too large on the second.

Comment: @Mico You're right. Done.